# Jquery find class - newly added to DOM

Tags: jquery

```
$('span.icon-user[data-userid='+this.userid+']').addClass('blahblah');
```

I'm using this code to add a class but it fails on jquery newly created content added to the DOM. Should this pick up newly add SPAN's with Class 'icon-user'?

thankyou

Comment: could ypu post a jsfiddle?

Comment: Also ensure that this.userid contains valid value

Comment: `jquery newly created content added to the DOM` So how do you add it?

Comment: This will only run on load. you will need to re-run this each time a new DOM element is added.

Comment: I think you need to add extra `" "` while searching for `data-userid` like `$('span.icon-user[data-userid=" '+this.userid+' "]').addClass('blahblah')`;